# Pandas dataframe groupby to calculate population standard deviation

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statistics

I am trying to use groupby and np.std to calculate a standard deviation, but it seems to be calculating a sample standard deviation (with a degrees of freedom equal to 1).

Here is a sample.

```
#create dataframe
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2],'B':[1,2,1,2],'values':np.arange(10,30,5)})
>>> df
   A  B  values
0  1  1      10
1  1  2      15
2  2  1      20
3  2  2      25

#calculate standard deviation using groupby
>>> df.groupby('A').agg(np.std)
      B    values
A                    
1  0.707107  3.535534
2  0.707107  3.535534

#Calculate using numpy (np.std)
>>> np.std([10,15],ddof=0)
2.5
>>> np.std([10,15],ddof=1)
3.5355339059327378
```

Is there a way to use the population std calculation (ddof=0) with the groupby statement? The records I am using are not (not the example table above) are not samples, so I am only interested in population std deviations.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can pass additional args to `np.std` in the `agg` function:

```
In [202]:

df.groupby('A').agg(np.std, ddof=0)

Out[202]:
     B  values
A             
1  0.5     2.5
2  0.5     2.5

In [203]:

df.groupby('A').agg(np.std, ddof=1)

Out[203]:
          B    values
A                    
1  0.707107  3.535534
2  0.707107  3.535534
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried "df.groupby('A').agg(np.std(ddof=0))", but I did not try adding the ddof in the agg parenthesis. I'll mark your reply as the answer once I can in 8 minutes (you responded really quickly).

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that the same result can be achieved without importing numpy, as follows: df.groupby('A').agg('std', ddof=1)

Answer (score 8):

**For `degree of freedom = 0`**

(This means that bins with one number will end up with `std=0` instead of `NaN`)

```
import numpy as np


def std(x): 
    return np.std(x)


df.groupby('A').agg(['mean', 'max', std])
```