# PANDAS: Find standard deviation for column based on other column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

As you can see below I have different 'tickers' in my dataframe and I would like to calculate the standard deviation for 'lret' column but for each individual ticker. At the moment it is calculating the entire column as a row. How can I calculate the standard deviation for each ticker in the dataframe? Any help would be appreciated. Also please see the function below for what the code is currently doing.

#### Dataframe output

```
        price       date ticker      lret       std
0  104.000000 2016-07-01      A       NaN  0.019456
1  104.878151 2016-07-05      A  0.008408  0.019456
2  104.411909 2016-07-06      A -0.004455  0.019456
3  104.931957 2016-07-07      A  0.004968  0.019456
4  104.421274 2016-07-08      A -0.004879  0.019456
....
         price       date ticker      lret       std
499  85.293078 2017-06-26      B -0.008033  0.019456
500  86.521425 2017-06-27      B  0.014299  0.019456
501  85.596974 2017-06-28      B -0.010742  0.019456
502  86.384999 2017-06-29      B  0.009164  0.019456
503  87.479757 2017-06-30      B  0.012593  0.019456
```

#### Function

```
def get_most_volatile(prices):
    """Return the ticker symbol for the most volatile stock.
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    prices : pandas.DataFrame
        a pandas.DataFrame object with columns: ['ticker', 'date', 'price']
    
    Returns
    -------
    ticker : string
        ticker symbol for the most volatile stock
    """ 
    # lret = Log Returns.
    # I would like to find the standard deviation for the log returns for each ticker in the dataframe
    prices['lret'] = np.log(prices['price'] / prices['price'].shift(1))
    prices['std'] = prices['lret'].std(skipna=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Dataframe grouping and standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014814/pandas-dataframe-grouping-and-standard-deviation)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `df.groupby` to get groups for any combination of features you need to group by. Then if you want to compute some aggregation per group you can use `.agg` or `.transform`.

Using `.agg` will create a new df with unique groups (tickers in this case) and the result of the aggregation function.

Using `.transform` will calculate the same aggregation but will broadcast to a dataframe / series of the same shape as `self` (self being the dataframe being grouped).

```
prices['std'] = prices.groupby('ticker')['lret'].transform('std')
```

Notice `['lret']` after groupby selects only that column before computing any aggregation.

Output

```
        price        date ticker      lret       std
0  104.000000  2016-07-01      A       NaN  0.006707
1  104.878151  2016-07-05      A  0.008408  0.006707
2  104.411909  2016-07-06      A -0.004455  0.006707
3  104.931957  2016-07-07      A  0.004968  0.006707
4  104.421274  2016-07-08      A -0.004879  0.006707
5   85.293078  2017-06-26      B -0.008033  0.011908
6   86.521425  2017-06-27      B  0.014299  0.011908
7   85.596974  2017-06-28      B -0.010742  0.011908
8   86.384999  2017-06-29      B  0.009164  0.011908
9   87.479757  2017-06-30      B  0.012593  0.011908
```

A similar example but using `.agg` would be

```
# st_dev = prices.groupby('ticker')['lret'].std() # for std deviation
# or
# st_dev = prices.groupby('ticker')['lret'].agg('std') # for std deviation
# or even
st_dev = prices.groupby('ticker')['lret'].agg(['mean', 'std']) # for mean and std deviation
```

Output

```
            mean       std
ticker
A       0.001011  0.006707
B       0.003456  0.011908
```

Read more in the [Groupby section of the user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25915225/6692898) for controlling the degrees of freedom in `std`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas' [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) operations:

Starting with your DataFrame `df`:

```
standard_deviations = df.groupby('ticker').std()
```